# CodeRush indents property initializers during "Introduce Local"

Tags: coderush

When I use the "Introduce Local" refactoring, CodeRush changes the indentation of my code. For example, before:

```
        DoSomething(new MyObject
        {
            PropertyA = "A",
            PropertyB = 2,
            PropertyC = true
        });
```

After:

```
        MyObject newMyObject = new MyObject
                    {
                        PropertyA = "A",
                        PropertyB = 2,
                        PropertyC = true
                    };
        DoSomething(newMyObject);
```

What I want:

```
        MyObject newMyObject = new MyObject
        {
            PropertyA = "A",
            PropertyB = 2,
            PropertyC = true
        };
        DoSomething(newMyObject);
```

I would like for CodeRush to respect my formatting. At the very least, I should be able to tell it how I prefer to indent my initializers. Are there any options that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inside the CodeRush Options Dialog (DevExpress | Options...), navigate to the Editor | Code Formatting section and tweak the desired settings. Look for the "Array, object and collection initializer" options. The options can be found on the Indentation, Line Breaks and Wrapping/Alignment option pages.

You may also want to play with options on the General options page to preserve the existing formatting.

Comment: I've spent over an hour in that area trying various permutations, to no avail. The options don't appear to do what they claim.

Comment: @MichaelLPerry What does built in VS formatting do if you temporarily DevExpress|Unload ? I use CR but not its formatting and recall VS does similar.

Comment: @MichaelLPerry What CodeRush version are you using? There was an issue with saving format settings. This was addressed in the latest release, v12.2.6.

Comment: @RubenBartelink I disabled CR and used VS Extract Method (the closest I could find for Introduce Local). The resulting method preserved the formatting of my initializer. So it doesn't look like it's VS doing it to me.

Comment: @AlexSkorkin I was on v12.2.5. I just updated, but the behavior was the same. I haven't yet gone through the options to see if there's a new setting. Does the above example work for you?

Comment: @MichaelLPerry For me that's a different matter - VS refactoring lands the code down in the location as a slab of text and then replaces whereas CR more intimately understands it. I'm asking whether autoformatting (CtrlK,CtrlD) and the autoformatting as you type when you type it normally (activated by return and ;) might actually land it that way (possibly in both cases). IOW I'd first eliminate VS' formatting from my enquiries before moving onto CR.